# Xamarin.IOS Auto Layout constrains для разных девайсов

Tags: ios, xamarin, storyboard

Всем привет. 
Пишу приложение на Xamarin.IOS. 
И у меня возникла небольшая неразбериха с constraints. 
У меня есть верстка для iPhoneSE(5,5s) и iPhone 6(7,8).
И вот там используются разные отступы между контролами и верхом экрана.
Например, для 6ки отступы между кнопками `20pt`, а на SE - `15pt`.

Подскажите можно ли как-нибудь в `storyboard` настроить эти отступы для каждого из девайсов?

Именно в storyboard, без программного указания отступов.
Пробовал `Vary for traits`, но потом понял что это не поможет.

Answer (score 0):

Единственный способ дифференциации по девайсам в Storyboard – это size-классы (vary for traits). В портретной ориентации все iPhone имеют один size-класс, поэтому, как вы правильно написали, они вам не помогут.

Нужного поведения можно добиться, если вместо отступа поместить между вашими view ещё один прозрачный view, плотно прилегающий к соседям. У этого view добавьте ограничение на одинаковую высоту (Equal Heights) с высотой экрана (корневой view вашего vc), и меняйте значение multiplier у этого ограничения, пока не получите нужный отступ между view на указанных устройствах (по моим подсчётам, значение multiplier должно быть между 0,02 и 0,03, без учёта других размеров экрана)

Comment: Выходит, что без программного задания размеров констрейна это будет проблематично.

Comment: В моём способе нет ничего такого, что нельзя сделать в сториборде.